# Get the records from the latest upload

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a SQL table and I'm using Entity Framework Core. During upload of records from an Excel file to this table I also add a column of "upload date" (`datetime`) which is a simple `DateTime.Today`.

E.g:

```
record | id | employee | customer| project | hours | uploadDate |
```

Now I would like a view that only shows the latest upload of records. Do you know a good lambda/LINQ for it?

```
_context.TableWithRecords.Where(DateTime.Max?).ToList();
```

basically or something similar.

Comment: What do you mean by _latest upload of records_? All the records that have been uploaded today, or in the last week, or in the last month? Or all records since you last made an update (and if that is the case, where is that date stored)

Comment: And its `.Where(x > x.uploadDate > someDateTime)`

Comment: Or all records since you last made an update (and if that is the case, where is that date stored) <-- this. Since the last upload, and that upload will also be the closest in time to me since every uploads "uploadDate" is datetime.today. It is stored in an SqlTable called Products. I would like a list of them to show in a view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like this:

```
_context
    .TableWithRecords
    .GroupBy(x => x.uploadDate)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Key)
    .First()
    .ToList();
```

This will group by the upload date, then order by descending to make the most recently uploaded group the first group, then grab the first group and return all of those results.

Doing a test with the following sample data:

```
var dates = new List<TestRecord>
{
    new TestRecord { Record = "1", Date = new DateTime(2018, 8, 1) },
    new TestRecord { Record = "2", Date = new DateTime(2018, 8, 1) },
    new TestRecord { Record = "3", Date = new DateTime(2018, 8, 1) },
    new TestRecord { Record = "4", Date = new DateTime(2018, 8, 2) },
    new TestRecord { Record = "5", Date = new DateTime(2018, 8, 2) },
    new TestRecord { Record = "6", Date = new DateTime(2018, 8, 2) },
};
```

where `TestRecord` is defined as:

```
public class TestRecord
{
    public string Record { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

gives the desired output of:

```
4 - 02/08/2018 00:00:00
5 - 02/08/2018 00:00:00
6 - 02/08/2018 00:00:00
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thank you, and thank you for the extensive explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I would use two queries :

```
DateTime? maxDate = _context.TableWithRecords.Max(x => x.uploadedDate);
var result = _context.TableWithRecords.Where(x => x.uploadDate == maxDate).ToList()
```

Comment: No, only the most recent. So lets say there are only 10 records. five records have "uploadDate" '2018-08-01' and the other five have '2018-08-02' I only want a list of the latest ones.

Comment: Im sorry if I am not clear. So I will explain further. So, today for example, is 2018-08-11. And I surf to website and want to see the latest uploaded reports. If the latest uploadedDate is '2018-08-02' I only want those records.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is order by date to get the latest record - something like this:

```
var getMostRecentRecord = _db.UploadTable.Where(a=>a.Id == model.Id).OrderBy(a=>a.uploadDate).FirstOrDefault();
```

You don't want to List() as that will bring everything, but if you filter by Id then you'll only be looking at that record. If you want to get the latest from the table without a specific ID then do:

```
var getMostRecentRecord = _db.UploadTable.OrderBy(a=>a.uploadDate).FirstOrDefault();
```

this will show the latest upload record with out unique Id.